# location from browser save dinto postgis displayed via mapserver wrong

Tags: openlayers, postgis, openstreetmap, mapserver

I am getting the location of a browser and sending lon/lat to a postgis database via WKT (using php script)

the results i get are

```
Longitude: -1.323114
Latitude: 51.401409
```

this *should* be in Newbury, UK (where i work) but, somewhere along the stack, it is being located in central Russia.

stack is as follows
PostGIS -> MapServer -> OpenLayers

this is a non-base layer, base layer is Open Street Map with projections set to EPSG:4326

what is it i've done wrong?

MAP FILE:         http://pastebin.com/3K2CZcaR
OpenLayers (JS):  http://pastebin.com/1fAERFJb

Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Google Maps certainly accepts those coordinates (albeit in lat/lon order not lon/lat which is off the coast of Somalia). It looks like lon/lat is the correct order for postGIS to convert to usable geometry, too. What does your PHP script look like?

Comment: it simple fires a 1 line stored proc which takes long/lat

stored proc executes "INSERT INTO .... VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('POINT( x y)'))

should be really simple and easy...